# Copying binary files with NAnt

Tags: copy, nant, binaryfiles

Can anyone advise how to copy a binary file using NAnt?

The [docs](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/copy.html) state simply that:

> Binary files will be corrupted by the copy operation.

But don't offer any guidance on how to actually accomplish this.

So far I've tried using the following `copy` operation (which obviously isn't working):

```
<copy
  if="${file::exists(favicon.path)}"
  file="${favicon.path}" 
  tofile="${folder.web}/favicon.ico"
  overwrite="true" />
```

Comment: The docs state that binary files will be corrupted **if** filters are used. Since you don't use filters in your example the `copy` operation should work. I've used the `copy` task many times without any problems. Try something like `<echo message="copy ${favicon.path} to ${folder.web}" />` in order to check the contents of the properties used in your build script.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comments: `copy` only corrupts if filters are used.  Alternatively, use [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) inside an `<exec>` task.